# Terraform - Increment a Variable in a for_each Loop

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terragrunt

I am trying to figure out a way to add an incrementing number to resource.

Here is a snippet of my code. I would like to make the priority an incrementing number, instead of passing in a fixed number.

**Current Code**

```
resource "azurerm_firewall_network_rule_collection" "netrc" {
   for_each            = {for network_rule_collection in var.network_rule_collections: network_rule_collection.name => network_rule_collection}
   name                = "netrc-${each.key}"
   azure_firewall_name = var.afw_name
   resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
   priority            = var.priority
   action              = each.value.action
```

Basically, I want to look something like this:

```
     priority            = (each.index *  10) + 140
```

I tried to use *each.key*, but in this module, each.key is a string.

I also tried a counter but you cannot combine a counter with a for_each loop.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

EDIT

I ended up using index as suggested below.

```
  priority            = (index(var.application_rule_collections, each.value) + 100)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can try to use [index](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/index_function)

```
priority = index(var.network_rule_collections, each.value)  + 140
```

PS: you will probably have to modify it its just as an example

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

```
  priority            = (index(var.application_rule_collections, each.value) + 100)

```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to **pre-calculate** the priorities:

```
locals {
  priorities = {
          for idx, network_rule_collection in var.network_rule_collections: 
              network_rule_collection.name => idx * 10 + 140
          }
}
```

then

```
resource "azurerm_firewall_network_rule_collection" "netrc" {
   for_each            = {for network_rule_collection in var.network_rule_collections: network_rule_collection.name => network_rule_collection}
   name                = "netrc-${each.key}"
   azure_firewall_name = var.afw_name
   resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
   priority            = local.priorities[each.key]
   action              = each.value.action
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using index as suggested.

```
priority            = (index(var.application_rule_collections, each.value) + 100)
```